# How to enable desktop environment

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I just put on command line that to get straight into ubuntu shell. Can anybody help me to reinstall back the desktop environment?

Below were the command that i used:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity gnome-shell lightdm
sudo apt-get clean   
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 1):

Boot your computer ...

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and the password.

Now execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

Note : Rebooting Ubuntu operating system is not absolutely neccessary ... but it is recommended.

Update addressing your response that you still have a blank screen and can't access the desktop :

Execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity  
sudo reboot
```

Comment: +1 There is no need to install `lightdm` separately. `ubuntu-desktop` will pull it either way.

Comment: If it's booting straight to shell there's likely no need to go into tty1

Comment: @Pilot6 : Thank you very much - I just wanted to get sure - I removed the lightdm part from the answer. :)

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Nothing change. After reboot the screen still blank(black). I just can enter the shell using ctrl+alt+f1.

Comment: Im still have the blank screen

Comment: Still nothing change

Comment: @azamembong : I am running out of ideas - all this should have worked. Maybe something went terribly wrong when you performed what you described in your question ... it seems that unfortunately you will have to reinstall the whole Ubuntu operating system. Sorry for having to tell you this ! :)

Comment: Its okay. Im gonna wait for others to answer. If you have other solution just share here. Thanks anyway.